# Homomorphic image is projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I am reading about projective modules. I am kind of wondering

> if there exist an abelian group which is not projective but its homomorphic image is projective.

Thanks.

**Edit.** It seems that the question is the following: is there an abelian group which is not projective but all its non-trivial homomorphic images are projective?

Comment: The zero module is projective, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be projective, for example $P = \mathbb Z$, and let $M$ be **not** projective, for example $M = \mathbb Q$.  Let $P \times M$ is not projective and we have a surjection $P \times M \to P$ given by $(p, m) \mapsto p$.

Comment: @ Jim, thank you. I think there is a typo for the position $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$. Still, I am looking like $G$ is a abelian group which is not projective but its every homomorphic image is projective.

Comment: Every abelian group is a homomorphic image of itself under the identity map, so its impossible to have an abelian group which isn't projective but every homomorphic image is projective...

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective as an abelian group.